# Onclick event make working

Tags: javascript

```
var shot = document.getElementsByClassName ('sprite');  
shot.onclick = function (event) {
    alert(1);
}
```

I have this code and i have this in html

```
<a href="#" class="sprite" ></a>
```

But it doesn't work why?

Comment: have you tried `return false;` after `alert(1);`

Comment: still_learning it has a background so it is visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it like,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sprite')[0];
```

in order to select the first element of the returned array of elements.
Also include some text in your html in order to see the element and click it,

```
<a href="#" class="sprite" >test</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/USx2x/

Comment: From my experience, when assigning an event function, like onclick, to an array, it makes all the elements in the array have the function triggered when clicked. Is what I said just wrong, or is this a different situation?

Comment: @OriShuss i think you have accomplished this with jquery.

Comment: @melc I certainly have not, I don't use jquery.